# Python - Neaten up Code - Loops and Recursive features

Tags: python, loops, recursion

I have the below code that works fine. However Whilst i'm learning im trying to find ways to continually improve my code.
Would it be possible to make the below code neater in any way?

```
def isValidWord(word, hand, wordList):
   """
   Returns True if word is in the wordList and is entirely
    composed of letters in the hand. Otherwise, returns False.

    Does not mutate hand or wordList.

    word: string
    hand: dictionary (string -> int)
    wordList: list of lowercase strings
    """
    x=''
    if word in wordList:
        x=True
    else:
        x=False
    #dont mutate the hand so copy
    hand2=hand.copy()
    for letter in word:
        if letter in hand2.keys():
            hand2[letter]-=1
            if hand2[letter]<0:
                x=False
                break

        else:
            x = False
    return x
```

To run the code:

```
hand = {'r': 1, 'a': 3, 'p': 2, 'e': 1, 't': 1, 'u':1}

word = "rapture"

wordList = ['rapture','alex']
isValidWord(word, hand, wordList)
```

Comment: This probably belongs on [code review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/), not here

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it probably belongs on [codereview.se]

Comment: This would likely get downvoted on Code Review for not having a sufficient description of what the code is supposed to do. It would be on topic, but not a spectacular question.

Comment: Sorry guys! How easy is it to move questions? I'm still new to all this!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To handle counts properly:

```
from collections import Counter

def isValidWord(word, hand, wordList):
    # Check for membership first and early out if fails
    # Otherwise, see if the count of any letter in word exceeds that of the hand
    return word in wordList and all(hand.get(let, -1) >= cnt for let, cnt in Counter(word).items())
```

Comment: Turns out my revised answer is very similar to yours, +1

Answer (score 3):

With `all` and a `Counter`:

```
from collections import Counter

def isValidWord(word, hand, wordList):
    wc = Counter(word)
    return word in wordList and all(wc[c] <= hand.get(c, -1) for c in wc)
```

If you have very large lists of words, consider using a set instead for the O(1) lookup time.

Comment: This won't handle the counts, just whether or not the value exists. The original code was paying attention to `hand` counts.

Comment: @ShadowRanger you are right, the docstring was a bit confusing. I'll try to adjust.